# Making Graph with a Group within a Large Data in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I have a large dataset that I am trying to make a graph of. If I am using all the data, it would be easy since I can put all the data into the range.

However, I have to put in only a group. For example,

[image]

In this graph, I want to graph with only values that are group 1. I tried defining name that refers to:

`=IF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10=1,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$10)`

then put it in the data source - legend entries - edit - sceries Y values.

[image]

This is what I got. This graph includes group 2 and 3 in the graph and put the value as 0. However, I need to completely discard groups other than group 1 in the graph.

For my purpose, I can't use VBA,

Could you help me? It would be great if I can put some kind of define naming and putting it in the data source in the chart.

Comment: is your data sorted by group? (are all group 1 data located in a contiguous range?)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a pivot chart, there you can (interactively) filter your data.

Select your data, go to insert - pivot chart. Then set it up as in the picture below. (I've added a helper column: row number for easier plotting, you may not need that, depending on your real data).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I need it to be done by default without making change in the pivot filters. In other words, is there way to make a graph that by default look at the A column and draw graph with only group 1?

Comment: what about selecting only data of group A? "I need it to be done by default" - how Excel should know that you're interested only in group A?

Comment: Group and Value data keep changes and I would like the graph to change automatically as the data updates. And how Excel should know it is the question I am asking. I believe it can be done by defining name and using it for dynamic range, but couldn't come up with exact formula.